# How to export an array from Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome

There is a complex array in the program, I can check it at chrome console when debug. How can I export the array from chrome console?

I tried to right click at console and choose `Save as ...`. The file is not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

You can export the array/object in console to JSON file using following [snippet](https://gist.github.com/rekursed/3acdc93fe22ce6034cb5b1cbeb921f5a)

- Open Sources -> Snippets in the console, right click to make a new file. Call it `console-save.js`
- Paste the JavaScript code below into the snippet
- Right click on `consoleSave.js` and run the snippet.
- now you can call console.save() to download objects from the console!
  [image]

```js
(function(console){

    console.save = function(data, filename){

        if(!data) {
            console.error('Console.save: No data')
            return;
        }

        if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

        if(typeof data === "object"){
            data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
        }

        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
            e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a    = document.createElement('a')

        a.download = filename
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
        a.dispatchEvent(e)
    }
})(console)
```